# Unable to get "Submit" button to work using Node.js and the Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have simple piece of code to Add users in to my application which inserts the data in to my backend cassandra DB. For some reasons the Submit button is not working. It won't give any error.

JS file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');

var client = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints : ['<DatabaseIP>']});
client.connect(function(err, result){
    console.log('cassandra connected: adduser');
});

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('adduser');
});

var upsertUser = 'INSERT INTO tablename(username, password, email, name) VALUES(?,?,?,?)';

router.post('/', function(req, res){
    client.execute(upsertUser, [req.body.username,req.body.password,req.body.email,req.body.name],
    function(err, result){
        if(err){
            res.status(404).send({msg: err});
        } else{
            console.log ('User Added');
            res.redirect ('/users');
        }
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Jade file:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 Add User
    form#formAddUser(name="adduser", method="post", action="/adduser")
    div
        input#inputUserName(type="text", placeholder ="Enter Username", name="username")
    div
        input#inputPassword(type="password", placeholder ="Enter Password", name="password")
    div
        input#inputEmail(type="text", placeholder ="Enter Email Address", name="email")
    div
        input#inputName(type="text", placeholder ="Enter Full Name", name="name")
    div
        button#btnSubmit(type="submit") Submit
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Look at the generated HTML!**

```
<h1>Add User</h1>
<form id="formAddUser" name="adduser" method="post" action="/adduser"></form>
<div>
  <input id="inputUserName" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username"/>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="inputPassword" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password"/>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="inputEmail" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="email"/>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="inputName" type="text" placeholder="Enter Full Name" name="name"/>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Your button isn't inside the form (and nor are any of the other controls).

You need to indent them to get them to be part of the form.

```
block content
    h1 Add User
    form#formAddUser(name="adduser", method="post", action="/adduser")
        div
            input#inputUserName(type="text", placeholder ="Enter Username", name="username")
        div
            input#inputPassword(type="password", placeholder ="Enter Password", name="password")
        div
            input#inputEmail(type="text", placeholder ="Enter Email Address", name="email")
        div
            input#inputName(type="text", placeholder ="Enter Full Name", name="name")
        div
            button#btnSubmit(type="submit") Submit
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
form#formAddUser(name="adduser", method="post", action="/adduser")
```

to

```
form#formAddUser(name="adduser", method="POST", action="/")
```

As to current post request handling is written for '/', not '/adduser' and method text

Comment: Change the post from lowercase to uppercase